# Can I have a .count variable in an HTML header in the pipe in a one-liner

Tags: powershell, count, where-clause, sql-like

This is a simplified example using `Get-Process` with a where clause. I have several HTML outputs I'm doing and I'd like to know if I can get the count of all objects limited by the where displayed in the HTML title called in the same line of code.

I don't want to do it in an additional line and was playing with `Measure-Command` and `$_.count`, but it was throwing away the data if I had it on the end of the pipe. Is anyone familiar with the syntax I should be using?

```
$processes = get-process | where { $_.name -like "s*"}

$a = "<style>"
$a = $a + "BODY{background-color:white;}"
$a = $a + "TABLE{border-width: 1px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;border-collapse: collapse;}"
$a = $a + "TH{border-width: 1px;padding: 0px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;background-color:#CCCCCC}"
$a = $a + "TD{border-width: 1px;padding: 0px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;background-color:white}"
$a = $a + "</style>"

$processes | select * | convertto-HTML -head $a -body "<H2>Number of processes $_.count</H2>" | out-file c:\TEMP\COUNTTEST.htm

ii c:\TEMP\COUNTTEST.htm
```

I'd like the output to look like this(with the count of processes beginning with "S" in the title - 33 in this case):

```
----------------------------------
Number of processes 33

__NounName  Name            Handles VM          WS  
process      SCNotification 295     243159040   8953856
```

Comment: Have you tried this `"<H2>Number of processes $($processes.Count)</H2>"` ?

Comment: That worked. is that all it was? Brackets and a preceding $? Thanks man! Why is the $ variable symbol in front of the brackets required?

Comment: The `$()` is called [subexpression](http://blogs.technet.com/b/stefan_stranger/archive/2013/09/25/powershell-sub-expressions.aspx), it used to evaluate code inside and output result. PS is smart enough to expand variables in strings, but when accessing object's properties inside quoted string you have to use subexpression.